# Optimize time for a elasticsearch query using fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

The below search query is taking around 2356 ms to fetch 50 records. 
Fuzziness leads to slower search. How can I improve performance using Fuzziness?
(Highlight cannot be skipped)

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "shall have the right",
          "fields": [
            "subType",
            "title",
            "type",
            "content"
          ],
          "fuzziness": "AUTO",
          "minimum_should_match": "80%"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "shall have the right",
          "fields": [
            "subType",
            "title",
            "type",
            "content"
          ],
          "type": "phrase",
          "slop": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg_example": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type.keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": "unified",
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell if you conducted some experiments to identify that fuzziness is the slowest part? Did you try using [profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) to identify the slowest part? It would be helpful to provide a couple of example documents.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Thanks for your time and  reply. After some research I found out that Highlight is the slowest part. The same query without highlight is 10x faster. Do you have any idea on how I could optimize highlight query?